# What dialect is "I be doing this"?

Tags: dialects, word-usage

In which part of the world do people use sentences like "I be doing this" (missing out the 'will' after the 'I')? Sounds like some of the 'street-ghetto' to me. What is it exactly?

Comment: Sounds like something a Pirate would say.

Comment: There is no "will" omitted. This is a non-standard form of the present (_I am doing_)

Comment: @StuR: that is because the stereotypical [pirate speech](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Talk_Like_a_Pirate_Day) is basically [West Country speech](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/West_Country_dialects)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It is not an accent, but a feature of some nonstandard dialects. As Peter Trudgill [has written:](http://www.phon.ucl.ac.uk/home/dick/SEtrudgill.htm)

> Standard English has irregular forms of the verb *to be* both in the
>   present tense (*am, is, are*) and in the past (*was, were)*. Many
>   nonstandard dialects have the same form for all persons, such as *I be,
>   you be, he be, we be, they be*, and *I were, you were, he were, we were,
>   they were.*

In the United Kingdom, the use of *be* throughout the present tense is associated with the West Country.

Comment: I have also seen *be* instead of inflected forms used in Lewis Carroll's *Sylvie and Bruno* to mark the speech of fairies, though that's probably derived from a local dialect.

Answer (score 9):

This is an example of African American Vernacular dialect, not an accent. It expresses habitual behavior, as in "I be doing this every day" = "I do this every day" in standard American English.

Comment: It might be this, but see Barrie England's reply for another possibility

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/African_American_Vernacular_English
Also see:  Ebonics

Comment: @Colin: I was interested in Barrie's answer because I don't know much about the grammar of non-standard BrE dialects. It's nice to know that BEV/AAV/Ebonics isn't the only English dialect with this feature. I read the Labov essay a long time ago, but I know a bit about this form from everyday experience, especially from my time in the U of Iowa's Afro-American Studies classes back in the 1970s, my first wife's two years of teaching at Morris Brown College in Atlanta, & other things. An isolated _He knocked her up_ could mean two totally different things depending upon who said it & where.

Comment: @Zoot: I looked for specific documentation of this form on the Net but found none. I looked at both those articles before posting & was disappointed in them.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like south-western Brit. Eng. to me. This explains why it reminded one person of pirate's speech, pirates generally being given the accent of Long John Silver, who, I think, was from Devon or Cornwall, although it is not clear from Treasure Island.