# I be walking down the street with a friend and would answer a question

Tags: grammar

Can you help me to find out what kind of grammar is using here?
"I be walking" is in which tense and what does it mean?

as far as i know, we can say 
"I am walking"
"I was walking"
but 
"I be walking" ??????

Comment: There are related questions [here](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/209531/can-i-be-ever-be-considered-correct)  and also [here](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/93231/what-dialect-is-i-be-doing-this)

Comment: It's in the piratical. And '... what kind of grammar is using here?' is a non-standard middle usage.

Comment: "I be walking..." is the sort of phrasing that is at least caricatured as urban African-American vernacular (I don't know if it is "real" or not).  The typical meaning would be "I was walking...".

Comment: @HotLicks: I think i remember reading that in AAVE the "be" forms are used specifically for habitual actions, rather than progressive ones, so "I be walking" wouldn't be used in this context, but would be used to mean "I walk" (in general). I don't know if this is the case for all varieties, though.

Answer (score 3):

"I be walking" is not standard English. But it is common in some varieties of English; most notably [AAVE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/African_American_Vernacular_English), where it is has a distinct meaning from "I walking".

Comment: Can you say what the meaning is then?

Comment: The examples I've read tend to use _working_ rather than _walking_, and I don't know if things are different for verbs of motion; but as I understand it, _He working_ means he is at work at this moment, while _he be working_ means that he has a job, or habitually works.

Answer (score -1):

This statement seems ungrammatical to me.  Perhaps it's slang meaning "I'd be walking down the street."

Comment: "Shirks from grammar"?

Comment: @DanBron shirks grammar ?

Comment: _Shirk_ in the variants of English that I know means _avoid a task or responsibility_. Does it mean something else in Indian English?

Comment: @Dan He be shirking from grammar

Comment: @Colin I'm afraid my usage was incorrect.

Answer (score -1):

I suspect you have simply mis-heard. The usual sentence would be:

I'd be walking down the street with a friend and would answer a question.

Comment: I don't think could be a mis-hearing, because it's from [a book,](https://books.google.com/books?id=juDmQTcw57cC&pg=PA54&dq=%22I+be+walking+down+the+street+with+a+friend+and+would+answer+a+question%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=uciWVerlEcP2-AGT54GgCQ&ved=0CB0Q6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=%22I%20be%20walking%20down%20the%20street%20with%20a%20friend%20and%20would%20answer%20a%20question%22&f=false) but it could be a typo.