# Using "be" as it is, Whats difference between I be ving, I am ving

Tags: syntactic-analysis

I've seen sometimes this structure, "I be doing that" or " We be balling" What is the difference with " ı am doing that", " We are balling"

You can correct my mistakes.

Comment: Use of  "be" like this is (a) nonstandard dialect, or (b) subjunctive.  Subjunctive:  
The rules at my job require that I be smiling at all times.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What dialect is "I be doing this"?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/93231/what-dialect-is-i-be-doing-this)

Comment: In AAVE, the use of 'be' in this way usually represents continuing or habitual action.