# why people sometimes use be+verb+ing on internet?

Tags: grammar

I've come across some sentences that looks weird to me on internet,
don't know wheter there's a diffrece in sentences like

> I be smiling : I am smiling

or

> they really be looking like international stars : they really are looking like international stars

[image]
[image]

Comment: Compare [this question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/93231/what-dialect-is-i-be-doing-this) although the answers are brief; "I be" can be the subjunctive per [this question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/209531/can-i-be-ever-be-considered-correct).

Comment: I think this is a tendency in social media language rather than voluntary omissions of standard English, or a particular tense. This tendency is present and growing. Maybe worth investigating? Voted to reopen. This is a pertinent question.